# How do I combine the graphic of a ListPlot with the graphic of a Plot?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to combine the graphic of a `ListPlot` to the graphic of a `Plot`? (I need to plot a graphic of a function on the graphic of a ListPlot)

Comment: Many good examples in the help for `Fit[ ]` http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fit.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can combine any graphics with the `Show` function like so:

```
Show[myListPlot, myPlot]
```

This generalizes to combining any number of plots at once: `Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, ...]` or `Show[{p1,p2,p3,p4,...}]`

---

Reference and image source: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html

[image]

[image]

---

You can use `Epilog` as well if `Show` is not stacking the graphics in the correct order, but combining more than 2 graphics with Epilog will be unwieldy.

Comment: I don't understand your last line... Care to explain why `Epilog` is overkill or what you mean by "stacking order"?

Comment: You should post the comments to other answers as comments there for several reasons, not the less important is that the current answer could be deleted in the future and others could be posted

Comment: @d00b: If you look at the documentation, Epilog's explicit stated purpose is to render a graphic on top after the first graphic has been made (e.g. to allow overlays and masks and watermarks), while the purpose of Show is to combine 2D and 3D graphics such as points and lines and surfaces. Additionally if you wish to combine more than 2 graphics, Epilog becomes very unwieldy. There is a time and place for each.

Comment: Thanks. So why does the mma documentation use `Epilog` in several places to overlay plots? One example is in Applications under `Histogram`.

Answer (score 9):

From your second line, I think `Epilog` is what you are looking for. Here's an example:

```
f[x_] := 1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-(x^2)/2];
ListPlot[
 Table[
  {x, PDF[NormalDistribution[], x]}, {x, -4, 4, 0.1}
  ],
 Epilog -> First@Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image]

Another way to do the same would be to use `Show`

```
p1 = ListPlot[
   Table[
    {x, PDF[NormalDistribution[], x]}, {x, -4, 4, 0.1}
    ]
   ];
p2 = Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[p1,p2]
```

---

On the other hand, if I was mistaken and you just wanted to combine them in the sense one next to the other, then you can use `GraphicsRow` or `GraphicsColumn`.

```
FullGraphics@GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]