# How to draw several graphics in one picture in Mathematica?

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

Just like `hold on` in Matlab.
I met this problem when i want to draw several lines in one picture.
The number of lines varies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I combine the graphic of a ListPlot with the graphic of a Plot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180373/how-do-i-combine-the-graphic-of-a-listplot-with-the-graphic-of-a-plot)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mathematica has a lot of constructs allowing you to combine plots, graphics and images.
I'll give you several examples. You can search the help system to find out more and understand the subtleties of the examples bellow:

[image]

**Edit**

If you want to read/write from/to files, the following code may serve you as a starting guide:

```
(*Create data*)
data = RandomReal[1, {8, 2}];
(*Put into a file*)
Export["c:\\test.tab", data, "Table"];
(*Read the file into another list*)
rdat = Import["c:\\test.tab", "Table"];
(*And Plot it like before*)
Graphics[{Line@#, Red, PointSize[Large], Point /@ #} &@rdat]
```

[image]

Comment: How about n lines in one graphic, n is read from some other files. Thank you

Comment: @User My last example, [and Szabolcs's last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641953/how-to-draw-several-graphics-in-one-picture-in-mathematica/6641986#6641986) address that. Perhaps you may clarify if something about your input prevents you from using these solutions

Answer (score 5):

*Mathematica* 8 introduced a new versatile function [Overlay](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Overlay.html), which can be used to graphically overlay any type of expression:

```
Overlay[{Graphics[{Yellow, Disk[]}], "Sun"}]
```

Comment: I haven't used this function so far, but I assume alignment may be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Show` to combine graphics objects.

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}], Plot[Cos[x],{x,0,10}]]
```

*EDIT* If you want to draw several lines, then build your `Graphics` object out of several lines:

```
Graphics[ Table[ Line[{{0,0}, {Cos[x],Sin[x]}}], {x,0,Pi,Pi/10} ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

combine graphics primitives like Szabolcs said:

> Graphics[ Table[ Line[{{0,0}, {Cos[x],Sin[x]}}], {x,0,Pi,Pi/10} ] ]

but if you are using plot then what you need to do is:

```
Show[Table[Plot[A Sin[x],{x,0,2 Pi}],{A,0.1,10}]]
```

Show command allows you to combine the graphics Table produces varying A, each one of them a Plot over x.