# How do I plot a function and data in Mathematica?

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, plot

Simple question but I can't find the answer.

I want to combine a ListLinePlot and a regular Plot (of a function) onto one plot.  How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I was sure that this question has been asked on SO before, but couldn't find it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I combine the graphic of a ListPlot with the graphic of a Plot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180373/how-do-i-combine-the-graphic-of-a-listplot-with-the-graphic-of-a-plot)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [Show](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html), e.g.

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3.5}], ListPlot[{1, 4, 9}]]
```

[image: Show output]

Note, if plot options conflict Show uses the first plot's option, unless the option is specified in Show. I.e.

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3.5}, ImageSize -> 100], 
 ListPlot[{1, 4, 9}, ImageSize -> 400]]
```

shows a combined plot of size 100.

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3.5}, ImageSize -> 100], 
 ListPlot[{1, 4, 9}, ImageSize -> 400], ImageSize -> 300]
```

Shows a combined plot of size 300.

Comment: @Chris Degnen Is there a way to do this on WolframAlpha? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Show[Plot[x^2%2C+{x%2C+0%2C+3.5}]%2C+ListPlot[{1%2C+4%2C+9}]] doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to using `Show` and combining two separate plots, is to use `Epilog` to add the data points to the main plot. For example:

```
data = Table[{i, Sin[i] + .1 RandomReal[]}, {i, 0, 10, .5}];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> Point[data], PlotRange -> All]
```

or

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> Line[data], PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually saw this one in the Mathematica help file for a Point, but I did not realize you could do it with a Line as well!